# Zone Aware Promise View not Displaying

Tags: angular, typescript

My view is not displaying the data that is being returned from the Service layer. I can see the data in the console.log so I know the data is being returned. Is there anything In the view that I need to add?

View

```
<table class="adminConfig-settings-list  table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Action</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <template ngFor let-status [ngForOf]="statuses">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>{{statuses.ConfigName}}</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{statuses.ConfigSetting}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </template>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Service Log array
[Service Log array has the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeMCB.png)

```
get(): Promise<AdminConfigModel[]> {
        console.log('Get AdminConfig');
        console.log(this.apiUrls.Get);
        var AdminConfig = this.http.get(this.apiUrls.Get, { headers: ServiceBase.headers }).map(x => <AdminConfigModel[]>x.json()).toPromise();
        console.log(AdminConfig);
        return AdminConfig;
    }
```

index.ts

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
        console.log(this.dataService.get().then(x => this.statuses = x));
        this.dataService.get().then(x => this.statuses = x);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that inside your template `status` should used instead of `statuses`

Ex.
`{{statuses.ConfigName}}`
should be changed to `{{status.ConfigName}}`

Similarly for the other occurrence.